# How to return data to a jquery ajax callback function?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How to return data to a jquery ajax callback function in which the data is coming from a PHP mysql query..

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $.post("getMySqlData", function(data){

        });
   });
</script>
```

here's the PHP code which perform the mysql query to select data from a mysql database

```
  <?php
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "problem2";
    $database = "scsi_test_log";
    $cxn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die ("couldnt connect to server");

    $query = "SELECT test_header FROM scsi_test";
    $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
  ?>
```

Comment: please read this: http://ditio.net/2008/07/17/php-json-and-javascript-usage/

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the result into an array, and echo that in [JSON encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php);

```
$rows = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $rows );
```

Comment: Does the echo return this data back to the callback function of the jquery ajax?